# Prove that all zeroes are equal

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Suppose all the zeroes of the polynomial $$p(x)=a_nx^n-a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots + a_2x^2-n^2bx+b$$ in $R[x]$ are positive reals. 
Prove that all the zeroes are equal.

First of all, I noted that $n$ is even. Note that the sign of $a_n \equiv a_{n-2} \equiv a_2 \equiv b$ since the signs are alternating.
Then, using the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{sym} r_1r_2 \cdots r_k = \frac{a_{n-k}}{a_n}$, we get $\displaystyle\sum \frac{1}{r_i} = n^2$.

But how to proceed?
I don't get any more idea.

Comment: $ax^2-4 b x +b=0$ has real distinct zeroes for $a > 4b$

Comment: @Raffaele Yeah true. And if $n$ is odd, then the statement becomes weird. I've quoted the question from the book properly. Anyway, for $n\geq 3$, does it hold?